# Android How to get browser history records in all the browser apps?

Tags: android, browser

I want to get all the browser history records from different browsers in android mobile phone? (Maybe as you know, there are usually more than one browser apps in a phone).

Comment: I would be a bit surprised if this information were available to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your browsers utilize this API to save history, this should be useful to you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html. Otherwise, this is not practically possible.

Comment: The API you provide just works on default browser.But thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your Activity to get history record in android browser.

```
 Cursor mCur = activity.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        mCur.moveToFirst();
        if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                Log.v("titleIdx", mCur
                        .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                Log.v("urlIdx", mCur
                        .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

You may also need add blow permission to get history.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

Comment: Hum,this code just works on the default browser in the phone, how about other browsers?