# Its possible to read the HTML from a Android browser?

Tags: android

I need to create an app that can read the HTML from a browser(like Chrome or native) in Android platform.

It's that possible? Without root

Thanks!!!

Comment: for rather obvious security reasons, I hope not (and I think not, too.)

Comment: Do you literally mean "I wish to spy on what the user is browsing"? Or do you just want to make an HTTP request from your own app, such as to a Web service?

Comment: You may in *some* cases be able to get *some of* the browser history and request the same content from the remote source yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361212/android-how-to-get-brower-history-records-in-all-the-browser-apps  Or you can make your own browser.

Comment: CommonsWare:I dont want to spy, I'm trying to offer a service for who install the app, but to return the right information i need to know some information from the html.
Chris: Now I'm reading the history but do to a request based on the history takes too long, so is not good enough. I'm willing to do the browser, but the problem is, why would they will use?. heheh!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to GET an html page? If yes this might help

```
public static String makeServiceCall(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        return response;
    }
```